# BeautifulSoup .get not returning 'href'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am working on creating a web-scraping tool that will download articles to txt files. I have created the soup with bs4 and pulled out the specific piece of html that contains the desired url for the article I want to download:

```
>>>prevLink = soup2.select('.previous_post')
>>>prevLink
[<span class="previous_post">Previous Post: <a href="http://www.mrmoneymustache.com/2018/11/08/honey-badger-entrepreneur/" rel="prev">An Interview With The Man Who Never Needed a Real Job</a></span>]
```

So far so good (I think). Then I try to use .get('href') to pull out the link, but it returns 'none'.

```
>>>print(prevLink[0].get('href'))
None
```

When I use .get('class') to select for the class, however, it seems to work.

```
>>> print(prevLink[0].get('class'))
['previous_post']
```

I don't understand why .get('class') is acting differently than .get('href'). 
Thanks for looking.

Comment: The `class` attribute is on the `span` tag (which is the top tag you've selected), while the `href` attribute is on the `a` tag, inside the span. You probably need to select the `a` tag before `.get('href')` will work as you want it to.

Comment: Thanks! That helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prevLink` is not actually referencing a link, but `span` element.

Just get deeper to the `a` element with your selector:

```
prevLink = soup2.select_one('.previous_post > a')
print(prevLink.get('href'))
```

Comment: Thanks! The above returns: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str. However, the following returns the URL as a string.
 
>>> prevLink = soup2.select('.previous_post > a')

>>> prevLink[0].get('href')

Comment: @AndreOtte ah, of course, sorry, since it's a single element, you need to use `select_one()`.